# Filter the unique records in queryset based on a model field in django

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I have a model like below

```
class SafetyRead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    accession_number =  models.CharField(max_length=256)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    radiologist = models.BooleanField() 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'SafetyRead - %s'%self.accession_number
```

Usually when i had done the search in the below way i got results

**query**

```
SafetyRead.objects.filter(approved=False,radiologist=False)
```

**Result**

```
[<SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2983>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead- 2582>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2583>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2522>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2522>]
```

As you can observe from the above query result the last two records are duplicated with field `accession_number` i.e., `2522`

So i want to filter the unique SafetyRead object records according to field `accession_number` in the same queryset format like below(after removing duplicate accession_number 2522 record)

```
[<SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2983>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead- 2582>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2583>, <SafetyRead: SafetyRead - 2522]
```

So how to filter it ?

Comment: Which one from the two duplicated records you want to leave in? The one with the bigger id?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

try:

```
SafetyRead.objects.filter(approved=False,radiologist=False).distinct()
```

Comment: But by using `distinct` it was giving me `*** NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` error

Comment: Sorry I missed something in the docs, you can only pass a field to `distinct` if you're using postgres. I've updated the answer.

Comment: But if we use just `disticnt()` the result will be same because it will remove the duplicate records according to id, but we want to remove the duplicate records that contains duplicate `accession_number` model field value

Comment: According to the docs that isn't true `For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.`

Comment: but i am using mysql here so when i used `distinct('accession_number')`, it was complaining me the above pasted error, when i used the just `SafetyRead.objects.filter(approved=False,radiologist=False).distinct()` i am still getting the same queryset result with duplicate `accession_number 2522`, so what to do now ?